# How to compare a 2 .txt files with a python script?

Tags: python, linux

Please i have a python script that compares 2 .csv files that i want to change to compare 2 .txt files. The first .txt file contains 3 columns of IDs and the second .txt file contains Fasta sequences with their IDs. I want a script that compares the 2 files: when an ID from the first or the third column of the first file (ignore the second column because it's the same as the first column) finds its match from the second file, the output should be the ID from the first file and next to it the Fasta sequence matching that ID. Thank you! :)

```
   with open('data1.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        full_name = line.split('\t')
        accession_x = full_name[0]

        with open('data2.csv', 'r') as f1:
             for line1 in f1.readlines()[1:]:  # ignores the first line
                line1 = line1.replace("\n", "")

                full_name1 = line1.split(' ')
                accession_y = full_name1[0].replace(" ", "")
                accession_z = full_name1[1].replace(" ", "")
                main_accession = accession_x + " " + accession_z + " " + accession_y

                if accession_x == accession_z:
                    print(main_accession)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the filenames will have to be changed from 'data1.csv' to 'data1.txt', and 'data2.csv' to 'data2.txt'.

Secondly: it depends on how the text files are formulated. Your current code assumes that the lines in the first file are separated by tabs and the rows in the second file are separated by spaces. This can be seen from split('\t') and split(' '). If this assumption holds true, then the code should work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only described the formats of the files it's hard to give the exact code, but I made some assumptions and wrote one according to them.

```
 with open('file1.txt', 'r') as  f1:
        for line1 in f1.readlines():
            l1 = line1.strip().split('\t')

            with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
                for line2 in f2.readlines():
                    l2 = line2.strip().split(' ')

                    if l1[0] == l2[0]:
                        print(l1[0] + " " + l2[1] + " " + l2[0])
                    elif l1[1] == l2[0]:
                        print(l1[1] + " " + l2[1] + " " + l2[0])
```

The assumptions are,

- I assumed your first file has three columns which are separated by tabs.
- Out of them only the first and third columns should be compared with the second file.
- The second file has two columns, fist column with the ID second column with the sequence. (If other way around just change the numbers in the code)
- No headers are in either files, if there are just skip the first line of the files.

Comment: The second file doesn't have 2 columns it's a .txt file that have many Fasta sequences where each sequence has this format:    >sp|Q9NR77|PXMP2_HUMAN Peroxisomal membrane protein 2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PXMP2 PE=1 SV=3
MAPAASRLRAEAGLGALPRRALAQYLLFLRLYPVLTKAATSGILSALGNFLAQMIEKKRKKENSRSLDVGGPLRYAVYGFFFTGPLSHFFYFFMEHWIPPEVPLAGLRRLLLRLVFAPAFLMLFFLIMNFLEGKDASAFAAKMRGGFWPALRMNWRVWTPLQFININYVPLKFRVLFANLAALFWYAYLASLGK

Comment: Well that took me a while to understand. I changed the code to match the format of the second file. Also I saw that the code you have provided only checks the first column of the first file, not first and third both. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes you're right! it only checks the first column of the first file.

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much for trying to help me but unfortunately this script didn't work for me. :) :) :)

Comment: Really? My bad then. Since you already have a working script no point of debugging mine :)